# Probability of selecting at least one student from each of the four classes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

The question is :

> Suppose that a school band contains $10$ students from the freshman class, $20$ students from the sophomore class, $30$ students from the junior class, and $40$ students from the senior class. If $15$ students are selected at random from the band, what is the probability that at least one students from each of the four classes?

I think the total number of outcomes is: ${100 \choose 15}$

I suppose that $4$ students are selected from each of the four classes. Now I have $96$ students taken $11$, so it is: $96\choose 11$

The probability is: $13/37345$

I am so confused. Please tell me if I was right or wrong and give me a hint!

Comment: No that will overcount. This requires a very detailed application of Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, given each of the groups have different number of members in the band. I do not see an easy way.

Comment: @Math Lover: Yes there is overcounting; but there is also (more significant) under counting since OP didn't account for factors for picking a student from each class. Eyeballing, OPs probability estimate looks way too low.

Comment: @paw88789 Yes because OP just left it at ${96 \choose 11}$ and did not choose a member each from $4$ groups. You are right, the probability is way too low.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to inclusion-exclusion is to use the generating function
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{10} \binom{10}{k} x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{20} \binom{20}{k} x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{30} \binom{30}{k} x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{40} \binom{40}{k} x^k\right)=\left((1+x)^{10}-1\right)\left((1+x)^{20}-1\right)\left((1+x)^{30}-1\right)\left((1+x)^{40}-1\right).$$
The coefficient of $x^{15}$ turns out to be
$200911429227922000$,
which yields probability
$$\frac{200911429227922000}{\binom{100}{15}} = \frac{14165531225}{17861970522}$$

Comment: How did you calculate the coefficient?

Comment: I used WolframAlpha.  If you are solving the original problem by hand, I recommend inclusion-exclusion.  You can use my answer as a check.